# How to add .json file to static library in iOS?

Tags: ios, json

My .json file contains some confidential settings and I want to include it in static library.But while supplying my static library I just want to provide .a file of static library to my client and I don't won't them to use drag and drop method in order to use its functionality.How can I achieve adding .json file in .a static file?

Comment: Can you give some more information what you really want to do? Will this `json` file be loaded from server or is it going to be static and its parameters hard coded - so basically they will never change?

Comment: thanks for reply.Actually the contents of json file will be updated dynamically by the server and then I'm supposed to create static library using updated json file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot place any resource file inside .a file. Best option is to make a bundle file and keep the json file inside it. But then the your client can see those file if he wants to.

If confidentiality is a matter, another option is to create a class that returns this json as NSString.

For example :

```
@interface LibraryHelper

+ (NSString *)jsonConfig;

@end

@implemenatation LibraryHelper

+ (NSString *)jsonConfig {
  NSString *json = @"<your json string hard coded>";

}

@end
```

Comment: Note that raw strings can be extracted from the binary quite easily. If it is super confidential then you'd want to not store it plain.

Comment: thanks for reply.Using bundle one can easily view the contents of json. Is there any other solution through which I can provide confidential details to client but he/she cannot view it?

Comment: Use keychain if information is going to be very confidential.

Comment: @sumofighter666 can please explain in details how I can use keychain for storing json file?

Comment: Apple provides sample code - KeychainItemWrapper - [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_m.html). This code is not perfect, but it is easy to use. There are other wrappers available on github.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have the developer drag another file in along with the .a binary then you need to compile the json file into the binary itself - as a string then parsed at runtime.

Having said this, if you just need a few config params then you'd be better off just putting the values directly into variables.

Also check out iOS .framework bundles in Xcode 6, they provide a nice way to group your binary, header files and any additional resource files. In the Xcode 6 new project window choose Frameworks & Library > Cocoa Touch Framework.